# JQUERY - simulate target="_parent"

Tags: php, jquery, iframe

I have a site that operates out of an IFRAME.

Is it possible to  simulate `<a href="x" target="_parent"></a>` with jquery?

Comment: I have no idea what you just said. Maybe post some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a js redirect using

```
window.parent.location.href
```

Answer (score 2):

`window.parent` refers to the parent `window` object, so just modify...

```
window.parent.location.href
```